# What is happening with task if I close application C#

Tags: c#, task, backgroundworker

Background: I run an application with a task which prints 'task + number' in infinite loop. I want to know what is happeingn with the task when I close application and How I see it.

my example, which I use to see that run task:

```
//delegate to pring text in label
    private delegate void SetTextToControlDelegate(string text, Control control);

private void SetTextToControl(string text, Control control)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextToControlDelegate deleg =
            new SetTextToControlDelegate(SetTextToControl);

        this.Invoke(deleg, new object[] { text, control });
    }
    else
    {
        control.Text = text;
    }
}

//run a task
private void Run()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i++;
                string result = "task " + i.ToString();
                SetTextToControl(result, label1);

            }
        });
}

//button to run task
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Run();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SetTextToControl(ex.Message,label1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you close the entire application the Task is killed.

Comment: Task is killed. Thread belongs to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is a process. Process is a parent of threads. Process also manages memory. So, threads (tasks) and their memory belongs to process. If the application (process) closes, it removes all its children. Tasks are killed, memory is freed.

Answer (score 3):

The task will be aborted and your application will close. That's all.

The calling code might get some changes to clean up, but that all depends on the close state of the application (did it crash or not).

As a side note: Never use `Thread.Sleep` in a `Task`. It might cause deadlocks if the task is executed on the same thread. Use `await Task.Delay`.